# jquery call to event that close div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using this script in order to add button that popup div.

https://github.com/dlenhart/st-action-panel-git/blob/master/js/st.action-panel.js

If you click on the button again the div will be closed, but i also wish to add X button, in the div header, that will do the same action.

How do call the event `closePanelAnim` (i think)?

HTML:

```
<div class="st-actionContainer left-bottom">
    <div class="st-panel">
        <div class="st-panel-header"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="st-panel-contents">
            Some text
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="st-btn-container left-bottom">
        <div class="st-button-main"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.st-actionContainer').launchBtn( { openDuration: 500, closeDuration: 300 } );
});
</script>
```

Comment: just give as many buttons as you want the same `st-actionContainer` class and they will all trigger the same javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could trigger the click event for the main button:

```
$('#xBtn').on('click', function(){
    $('.st-button-main').trigger('click');
});
```